# NameValueCollection on Xamarin 4.5 .net

Tags: .net, xamarin

I have PCL project targeting 4.5 .net framework. 
I am importing System.Collections.Specialized on top of my file:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
```

but I am getting 'NameValueCollection could not be found' error.

Based on docs: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx

it should be available on 4.5 .net framework. 

 
I guess that because Xamarin is using some sort of class library subset. 
How do I know which classes are not available in Xamarin project? 
 Are there Xamarin-specific .net docs?
Why this specific NameValueCollection class isn't available? 
Sorry for a such lame question, but Xamarin is pretty confusing at start.

As a side note - I saw that people are creating c# core project which is supposed to be shared between all kind of platforms. What is the difference between creating PCL project and then including it into iOS/Android/WP8 project and C# core project (is it even possible)?

Comment: Are you looking for [docs.go-mono.com](http://docs.go-mono.com/)?

Comment: http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T:System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection  it's still there, isn't it?