# Xamarin Architecture supporting web service calls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, xamarin

I have tried a number of different configurations for a PCL Xamarin project in Visual Studio 2015 update 3 with Xamarin 4.1.2.18 (According to about box in visual studio)

What I want to do is make calls such as this below. My question is how do I avoid the conflicts of the type listed below? And what is the best way to make calls like this? In the Portable project? Platform (Replicated for each) or in a separate non portable class library?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiate the client for making calls
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static HttpClient CreateHttpClient()
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true };

        return new HttpClient(handler);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Make a request for data to the specified web service
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Returned data type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="url">Associated Url</param>
    /// <param name="token">Authorization token</param>
    /// <returns>Returns instance of the passed T type</returns>
    public T GetRequest<T>(Uri url, string token)
    {
        HttpClient client = null;
        T result = default(T);

        try
        {
            client = CreateHttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            HttpResponseMessage resp = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            result = resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //_log?.Debug("There was a general error with working with {0}", url, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            client?.Dispose();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Whenever I try adding a nuget package to the solution, I keep getting version conflicts such as the one that I got below when I added Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client to the IOS Project, a separate class library or  the Portable project.

No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b7
4>  7a5c561934e089" and "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"
4>  . Choosing "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrar
4>  ily.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784625/using-httpclient-in-a-xamarin-core-project

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Very helpful